# generic method with multiple type parameters in c#

Tags: c#

Thought I was doing something simple, but somehow can't make it even compile.

```
protected List<R> Retrieve<R>(T request)
```

I want to write a generic method that can return different responses base on the request type. So when I call a web api site, I may get different strong typed requests, but in this function, I will do the json serialization, send the request,  and deserialization the response back.

Looks like c# won't allow me to do this. Is there any workaround or I will need to write different methods for each request.

Comment: Try something like `protected List<R> Retrieve<T, R>(T request)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using two different type parameters, you must define two of them

```
protected List<R> Retrieve<T, R>(T request)
```

Note that one or both of them could be declared at the type (class/struct) level.

```cs
class C<T>
{
    protected List<R> Retrieve<R>(T request)
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

or

```cs
class C<R>
{
    protected List<R> Retrieve<T>(T request)
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

or

```cs
class C<T, R>
{
    protected List<R> Retrieve(T request)
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

This is comparable to the [Func<T,TResult> Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) which is declared like this

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T,out TResult>(T arg);
```

Comment: you need to return `default(List<R>);`

Comment: No, since C# 7.1 you can use [Default Literals](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/06/06/c-7-series-part-3-default-literals/). C# infers the type.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this being possible to is to use constraints like so:

```
// This is to constrain T in your method and call ToRType()
public interface IConvertableToTReturn
{
    object ToRType(object input);
}

protected List<TReturn> DoSomethingAwesome<T, TReturn>(T thing)
    where T : IConvertableToTReturn
{
    // Do what you need to do. (Return with thing.ToRType())
}
```